# How to safely install GNU/Linux distro on a Samsung UEFI enabled laptop

Tags: uefi, linux-distributions, liveusb

I have already bricked and replaced my Samsung Chronos Series 7 NP700Z3C laptop. I have discussed it in the following question:

[Why does my Samsung Chronos 7 not boot anymore after installing Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/549259/why-does-my-samsung-chronos-7-not-boot-anymore-after-installing-ubuntu)

Summary of the problem is that If you normally try to install Linux on it, your laptop will die.

I am a GNU/Linux user and I boot and install different distributions frequently. Now I want to know how I should deal with this laptop, should I always be afraid to boot a live GNU/Linux distro on it? Or is there a safe way to avoid this problem again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Samsung UEFI bug is not Linux-specific -- as [described by Matthew Garrett,](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/22855.html) it can be triggered under Windows, too. Disabling UEFI support in the laptop is the safest way to deal with it, but this will require re-installing Windows, and the installation media provided by Samsung probably don't support doing a BIOS-mode install. Thus, you may need to find installation media from another source. Personally, I'd return the laptop to the store for a refund and buy another brand, but if that's not an option, converting everything to BIOS mode is the safest (albeit awkward) solution.

With any luck Samsung will eventually release a fixed firmware, but I have no idea how long this will take to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Set the laptop to boot in BIOS/legacy mode/Compatibility Support Module (there should be some option somewhere) and you should be fine. Just don't boot it going the UEFI route.

Comment: I will try this as soon as my replacement laptop arrives.

Comment: I ordered another laptop and I hope samsung fixes it's buggy driver very soon.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.linuxnewshere.com/index.php/linus-torvalds-no-more-bricks-for-samsung-laptops) and to [committed patch](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=e0094244e41c4d0c7ad69920681972fc45d8ce34) to Linux kernel, most reliable way to avoid this is to disable UEFI mode - this patch simply disables boot if UEFI mode is detected to prevent possible bricking.

Comment: I look for a workaround to make sure when I boot a live disk/usb my system will not brick. Because I won't have a second chance.

Comment: before installing linux, go into BIOS  and turn UEFI off, or enable legacy boot mode. This will make sure that you laptop will NOT be bricked