# Confirmed success with installing linux on Samsung UEFI laptop?

Tags: linux, boot, bios, fedora, uefi

I am aware that the specific question and possible solution about this has been asked before:
[How to safely install GNU/Linux distro on a Samsung UEFI enabled laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/549941/how-to-safely-install-gnu-linux-distro-on-a-samsung-uefi-enabled-laptop)

However what I am looking for is 'confirmation' from someone that has actually tried this and it is successful with no problems, ie. disabling UEFI and secure boot and then installing linux? Specifically I have a Samsung Chronos NP700Z5C and will be installing Fedora 18. Call me paranoid, but I have yet to see someone state that this works with no problems and say 'cause I have done it'. There is no second chance for me if this goes wrong, no warranty I can rely on, and no way I can afford this to go horribly wrong. I hoped to dual boot but disabling UEFI will cause Win8 not to load, so I'll just go all Fedora on this one. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would disable UEFI in bios, then install Windows 7 with Ubuntu (dual-boot) - both Windows 7 and Ubuntu support booting without UEFI mode.

This is totally safe from bricking, and Windows 7 will work better than Windows 8 anyway.